# how to pass the predicted model output as another model input? (chaining models in tensorflow)

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I build a model in TF that preprocess 1D vectors in 2D spectrograms.

I now want to feed the 2D vectors to another model.

I try a bunch of things, and the one that seems closest to a solution for me would be:

```
def apply_predict(x):
    return preprocess_model.predict(x)

autoencoder.fit(  dataset.map(apply_predict) )
```

But TensorFlow does not allow me to do that:

```
RuntimeError: Detected a call to `Model.predict` inside a `tf.function`. `Model.predict is a high-level endpoint that manages its own `tf.function`. Please move the call to `Model.predict` outside of all enclosing `tf.function`s. Note that you can call a `Model` directly on `Tensor`s inside a `tf.function` like: `model(x)
```

But if I do as suggested, I got another error:

```
  ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_17" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 22169), found shape=(22169, 1, 128)
```

Which led me to inspect the output of `model(x)` and compare with `model.predict(x)`

and found that the `model(x)` is actually `(22169, 1, 128)` and it does not make sense of where it comes from:

`x` is shape 1D (22169)
`model.predict(x)` is shape (44, 128)
`model(x)` is shape (22169, 1 , 128) =>> why the 1D input vector is interpreted as num_samples ??

Can you show how to pass the output of a model into another one, like if it was:

`autoencoder.fit(  dataset.map(preprocess_model.predict) )`

and explain what difference between `model(x)` and `model.predict(x)` , and how to use `model(x)` as suggested by the TF error message, so that I get the desired output.

Please note I want to keep the model separated, because then when I train the `autoencoder` model, the loss function will be between the input and output, both spectrograms and not between raw input (1D vector) and spectrograms (2D vector).

Comment: Reproducible code is needed. Please share if possible.

Comment: Providing both models summary (layers input/output shapes) will be appreciated it to figure out the problem